# Difference between activeElement, elementFromPoint and target

Tags: javascript, dom-events, element

I would like to know the difference between the following methods and in which scenario each should be used. I have created a [Jsbin DEMO](http://jsbin.com/oRixedEF/1/edit?js,console,output) which shows all of these give the same result on click handler.

- `document.activeElement`
- `document.elementFromPoint(x,y)`
- `event.target`

Comment: Have you looked it up? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/) is usually a really good resource.

Comment: I have looked at MDN but it does not tell the difference between activeElement and target.

Comment: I want to know if I can always use `document.activeElement` inside clickhandler instead of `event.target`? What is the beneift and what is the harm.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is the context.

`document.activeElement` returns the document's active element, the element that's currently under focus. `event.target` returns the node which is targeted by an event. If the event isn't `click`, `focus`, or something similar. They wouldn't be the same.

`activeElement` exists on the `document` object, while `target` only exists when there's an event.